# How Can We Fill Missing Values Within a Group in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to fill the missing values in a dataframe after I impute missing months.  In my real-world data, these missing months are extremely important for joining other dataframes, so filling these missing items also are important.

```
library(janitor)

df.1 <- tribble(
~customer_id, ~cust_nm  ,~period, ~cost1, ~cost2 ,
'cust1', 'pizzaco', as_date('2022-01-01'), 5, 10,
'cust2', 'sodaco',as_date('2022-03-01'), 5, 10,
'cust1', 'pizzaco', as_date('2022-04-01'), 5, 10,
'cust2', 'sodaco', as_date('2022-05-01'), 5, 10,
)

# predetermine which months to report on
reporting_months  <- data.frame(repmonths = seq.Date(from=ymd('2022-01-01'), ymd('2022-06-01'),by="1 month")) 


cust_list <- df.1 %>% 
  select(customer_id,cust_nm) %>% 
  unique()


for (i in 1:nrow(cust_list)) {
test <- df.1 %>% filter(customer_id == cust_list$customer_id[i]) %>% 
  group_by(customer_id, cust_nm, period) %>% 
  full_join(reporting_months, by = c('period' = 'repmonths')) %>% # this successfully imputes the missing months
  fill(c(customer_id, cust_nm), .direction = "down") # but this seems to have no impact on the data
  summarise(cost1 = sum(cost1, na.rm = T),
            cost2 = sum(cost2, na.rm = T),
            total = cost1 + cost2) %>% 
  adorn_totals(where = 'row') 

}
```

any suggestions on other things to try?  It doesn't create an error, it just doesn't work as intended.  The expected output would be something like this:

```
customer_id  cust_nm  period       cost1  cost2
cust2        sodaco   2022-01-01    0     0
cust2        sodaco   2022-02-01    0     0
cust2        sodaco   2022-03-01    5     10
cust2        sodaco   2022-04-01    0     0
cust2        sodaco   2022-05-01    5     10
cust2        sodaco   2022-06-01    0     0
```

Comment: Try `ungroup()` before running `fill()`.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it not using `for-loop`

##### Data preparation

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyr)

df.1 <- tribble(
  ~customer_id, ~cust_nm  ,~period, ~cost1, ~cost2 ,
  'cust1', 'pizzaco', as_date('2022-01-01'), 5, 10,
  'cust2', 'sodaco',as_date('2022-03-01'), 5, 10,
  'cust1', 'pizzaco', as_date('2022-04-01'), 5, 10,
  'cust2', 'sodaco', as_date('2022-05-01'), 5, 10,
)

# predetermine which months to report on
reporting_months  <- seq.Date(from=ymd('2022-01-01'), ymd('2022-06-01'),by="1 month")
```

##### Processing with `tidyr::complete`

```r
df.1 |>
  bind_rows(tibble(period = reporting_months)) |>
  complete(period, customer_id, fill = (list(cost1 = 0, cost2 = 0))) |>
  group_by(customer_id) |>
  mutate(cust_nm = first(cust_nm, na_rm = TRUE)) |>
  arrange(customer_id, period) |>
  filter(!is.na(customer_id)) |>
  ungroup()

#> # A tibble: 12 × 5
#> # Groups:   customer_id [2]
#>    period     customer_id cust_nm cost1 cost2
#>    <date>     <chr>       <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 2022-01-01 cust1       pizzaco     5    10
#>  2 2022-02-01 cust1       pizzaco     0     0
#>  3 2022-03-01 cust1       pizzaco     0     0
#>  4 2022-04-01 cust1       pizzaco     5    10
#>  5 2022-05-01 cust1       pizzaco     0     0
#>  6 2022-06-01 cust1       pizzaco     0     0
#>  7 2022-01-01 cust2       sodaco      0     0
#>  8 2022-02-01 cust2       sodaco      0     0
#>  9 2022-03-01 cust2       sodaco      5    10
#> 10 2022-04-01 cust2       sodaco      0     0
#> 11 2022-05-01 cust2       sodaco      5    10
#> 12 2022-06-01 cust2       sodaco      0     0
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>